# Aggregate attribute based on symbology classes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I was wondering if there is an existing tool/way to aggregate an attribute based on the active symbology of a layer.

For instance, if I have a point layer with population and distance from the city center for each point and I create a specific symbology for the distance (let's say 0-1km, 1-5km 5++km) to get the total number of people within each class.

I would like to avoid creating dummy reclassified attributes if possible.

Comment: Are you talking about something like `aggregate('pointlayer','sum',"population","distance"<1000)`? Just adjust the distance for each symbology class.

Comment: yeah, something like this, but i want it to read directly from the symbology so that i don't have to it manually.

Comment: What do you mean with reading data from the symbology? Your symbology is based on a field or on an expression?

Comment: on a specific field

Comment: So you want to aggregate based on a specific field, not on the symbology, did I understand you right? Would using the aggregated algorithm solve your problem? See the documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate

Comment: There's are a few variables that you can try o use in the group argument, symbol_label, symbol_color or symbol_id

Comment: right click layer - show feature count

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your interest. I created a pyqgis script that does exactly what I wanted, I will post it as soon as I make it a bit more presentable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is more or less what I did. It was fine for me to just have the results printed in the terminal.

The symbology was drawn from a qml file and I don't know if this works with ad-hoc symbologies.

Finally, I am sure that there is a way to integrate the aggregate function, but for I just needed to sum.

```
from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def sumBySymbologyClass(layer, attribute):
    layer.exportNamedStyle(d)
    s = d.toString()
    root = ET.fromstring(s)

    for attr in root.iter('renderer-v2'):
            classified_attribute=attr.attrib['attr']
            
    i=0
    for elem in root.iter('range'):
        class_pop=[]
        lower = elem.attrib['lower']
        upper = elem.attrib['upper']
        if i==0:
            features = layer.getFeatures('"{}" >= {} AND "{}" <= {}'.format(classified_attribute, lower, classified_attribute, upper))
        else:
            features = layer.getFeatures('"{}" > {} AND "{}" <= {}'.format(classified_attribute, lower, classified_attribute, upper))
        i+=1
        for feature in features:
            sumAttribute = feature[attribute]
            class_pop.append(sumAttribute)
        print('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(classified_attribute, lower, upper, sum(class_pop)))
```